# Левый(,)нижний от себя угол

Tags: пунктуация

Верно ли расставлены знаки?

*Он попал в левый, нижний от себя угол*

И, если можно, приведите правило, поясняющее пунктуацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая здесь может понадобиться только в экзотическом контексте, когда *левый* угол ромба (его можно определить по направлению вписанной надписи, напр. "Спартак") одновременно и однозначно является *нижним* углом для бросавшего в него дротик (этим углом вниз был подвешен ромб). Если же это левый нижний *угол ворот*, запятая **ошибочна**, поскольку невозможно определить угол, "нижний от себя" (он *для всех* нижний). "От себя" (при левом нижнеи угле ворот) лучше заключить в скобки, если это упоминание вообще требуется (чтобы ни в коем случае не подумали, что "от вратаря"). Либо можно так:

> Он попал в нижний, *левый от себя* угол.

Здесь уточняющее определение "левый от себя" (который из двух нижних) отделено запятой.

Правило:

> *Обособление уточняющих согласованных определений – явление достаточно редкое и во многом зависит от воли пишущего. Обычно определения с
> уточняющим значением рассматриваются как однородные, то есть запятая
> ставится не с двух сторон, а с одной – между определениями.*

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за столь развернутый ответ! Да, я ошибся при формулировке.. Вы верно переформулировали: он попал в нижний, левый от себя угол. И правило, как раз о котором думал. Ещё раз спасибо и хорошего Вам дня!